# Data recovery: pulled out USB while writing data, now flash "drive not found"

Tags: usb, data-recovery, detect

I accidentally pulled out a USB drive while writing on it (I thought it has finished writing).

Now this drive is seen by both Ubuntu 18.04 PC and the Win10 laptop, but when I try to open it, it writes "drive not found".

So lots of instructions in the internet refer to formatting/resetting/rewriting usb-controller etc, which will kill all info on the drive.

Is there any way to recover the data on the flash drive? The data is not critical, but it would be very nice to have.

dmesg:

```
[64498.275] usb 1-10: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[64498.423] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=1201, bcdDevice= 0.00
[64498.423] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[64498.424] usb-storage 1-10:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[64498.424] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-10:1.0
[64499.431] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     NAND     USB2DISK         0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[64499.431] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[64499.432] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: Sorry I formulated it incorrectly. I changed the topic and description: the usb drive IS seen by both Ubuntu 18.04 PC and the Win10 laptop, but when I try to open it, it writes "drive not found".

Comment: ok. last part is relevant: "Can you provide (error) messages from for instance dmesg when you insert the USB? "  Last 20 lines after should be enough. Edit them into the question

Comment: This is probably a software problem, a corrupted file system. You can analyze it, and I think, fix it according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) answering another AskUbuntu question.

Comment: I added all new messages I get in dmesg after inserting usb-disk.

Comment: Are there data in the USB drive that you *have to* recover? In that case I suggest that you try Testdisk and Photorec from https://cgsecurity.org. If Testdisk does not work, you can rely on Photorec, but (via Photorec) the file names are lost and it will probably be a lot of work.

Comment: As far as I remember there is no critically important data on that drive, so I can try. My other colleague suggests that the controller firmware is erased so I either have to reinstall the firmware (and therefore delete the data) or go to specialized data-recovery companies, who will solder an external controller to the flash memory and recover the data.